# Sumar una columna de datagrid dependiendo de otra columna

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, datagrid

tengo una duda... quiero sumar una columna [Total] y mandarlo a un Textbox, donde en otra columna[Folio] se repita por ejemplo:

```
Folio  Total
3      45.23
3      224.56
3      4.56
4      56.00
5      12.02
6      8.50
```

La respuesta que espero es el total del las filas con el mismo folio, en este caso seria 274.35.

Esto solo me trae el resultado de la primera fila y no de los folios repetidos.

```
Decimal sumcol = dataGrid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.Cells[1].Value));
textBox7.Text = Convert.ToString(sumcol);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la siguiente consulta de Linq para conseguir lo que deseas, en este caso paso el número del folio que quiero sumar y sólo te devuelve la suma de los valores de ese folio:

```
decimal sumcol = dataGrid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(x => x.Cells[0].Value != null && x.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "3").ToList().Sum(y => Convert.ToDecimal(y.Cells[1].Value));
```

Comment: solo le pase desde un forearch el numero de folio para hacerlo dinamico y funciona, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agrupar por folio pero vas a tener mas de un resultado, por lo tanto tendras un total por cada folio, no se podra mostrar en un textbox.

```
var query = from row in dataGrid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
             group row by row.Cells["Folio"].Value into g
            select new {
               Folio = g.Key,
               Total = g.Sum(x=> Convert.ToDecimal(x.Rows["Total"].Value))
            };

List<string> temp = new List<string>();
foreach(var item in query)
{
  temp.Add(string.Format("folio: {0} total: {1}", item.Folio, item.Total));
}
TextBox1.Text = string.Join("\n", temp);
```

pero sera un item por cada folio por eso es que podrias unirlos en nca cadena y mostrarlo en varias lineas si haces el textbox multiline

Esta ultima parte tambien podria ser

```
List<string> query = from row in dataGrid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                     group row by row.Cells["Folio"].Value into g
                     select string.Format("folio: {0} total: {1}", g.Key, g.Sum(x=> Convert.ToDecimal(x.Rows["Total"].Value)).ToString("N2")); 
TextBox1.Text = string.Join("\n", temp);
```

directo una lista de string que muestras directo

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría algo como esto:

Obtener los Folios de la 1era Columna:

```
 List<int> folios = new List<int>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (item.Cells[0].Value!=null)
                {
                  folios.Add(int.Parse(""+item.Cells[0].Value));
                }
            }
```

Obtener los repetidos, aunque pueden ser mas de 1 repetido, en el ejemplo solo tomaría el 1er repetido que obtenga.

```
        var query = folios.GroupBy(x => x)
           .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
           .Select(y => y.Key)
           .ToList();

        int repetido = query[0];
```

Sumar esos repetidos

```
        int suma = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (item.Cells[0].Value != null && int.Parse(""+item.Cells[0].Value) == repetido)
            {
                suma += int.Parse(""+item.Cells[1].Value);
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("" + suma);
```